# Add to cart buttons functionality

Tags: javascript, button, cart

I have products and a cart. Each product has an "Add to cart" button and when you click it, it'll add the product to the cart and the inner text of the button will be "In cart" and the button will be disabled. My problem is that I can't figure out how to enable the button and change the inner text back to "Add to cart" after I remove the product from the cart or clear it.

This is the JS for adding the product:

```
let addBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("bag-btn");
for (let i = 0; i < addBtns.length; i++) {
  const btn = addBtns[i];
  btn.addEventListener("click", addToCart);
}

function addToCart(e) {
  const button = e.target;
  button.innerText = "In Cart";
  button.disabled = true;
  const title = button.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent;
  const price =
    button.parentElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.children[0]
      .textContent;
  const img = button.parentElement.children[0].src;
  addItemToCart(title, price, img);
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, img) {
  const newRow = document.createElement("div");
  newRow.classList.add("cart-item");
  newRow.innerHTML = `
  <img src="${img}" alt="product" srcset="" />
  <div>
  <h4>${title}</h4>
  <h5>${price}</h5>
  <span class="remove-item">Remove</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
  <p class="item-amount">1</p>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>`;
  cartContent.append(newRow);
}
```

this is the remove product function:

```
cartContent.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("remove-item")) {
    let removeItem = e.target;
    cartContent.removeChild(removeItem.parentElement.parentElement);
```

SO, how to change the button text and functionality back to normal after I remove the product from the cart? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not do the same delegation for the add as you do for the remove?

I do not have your HTML, but something like this

```
cartContent.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove-item")) {
     tgt.closest("whatever container").remove();
     tgt.closest("whatever container has button").querySelector(".bag-btn").textContent="Add to cart";
  }
  else if (e.target.classList.contains("bag-btn")) addToCart(tgt)
 })
```

and have

```
function addToCart(button) {
  // const button = e.target;
```

All those `parentElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.children[0]` are horrific

Instead use `button.closest("whatever container").querySelector("some selector")`

Comment: Lmao bro I laughed too at this, man said it's horrific!! My bad you had to see it, this my 2nd month learning JS, I know it's shit but it's my best for now lol I'll try what you said when I can and get back to you. Thanks for the answer and for cracking me up lol